# Array.indexOf or between?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently designing a GUI that allows the user to define some logic.  I don't want it getting too complex, so I am limiting it to a single set of brackets. So, the idea is to check that between the opening and closing brackets there are not any other opening brackets.

eg. `IF ( a + b OR **(** b+ c)` would alert with error.

So I decided with the route of:

- Find the first open bracket
- Find the first close bracket
- Using those indices search between and find any open brackets
- If any open brackets are found display an error
- Continue the loop for any other logic

Here's the code. I think its pretty horrific and I am sure there must be a better way to do this.  Some kind of IndexOf maybe.

```
<select rel="OpenBracket" id="open1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="(">(</option>
</select>
Some True/Fale here
<select rel="CloseBracket" id="close1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=")">)</option>
</select>
AND
<br />
<select rel="OpenBracket" id="open2">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="(">(</option>
</select>
Some True/Fale here
<select rel="CloseBracket" id="close2">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=")">)</option>
</select>
<button onclick="javascript:TestingRules();">Check</button>
```

---

```
function GetOpenBrackets() {
    var openBracketArray = [];
    jQuery('[rel="OpenBracket"]').each(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val() == "(") {
            openBracketArray.push(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
        } else {
            openBracketArray.push(jQuery(this).val());
        }

    });
    return openBracketArray;
}

function GetCloseBrackets() {
    var closeBracketArray = [];
    jQuery('[rel="CloseBracket"]').each(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val() == "(") {
            closeBracketArray.push(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
        } else {
            closeBracketArray.push(jQuery(this).val());
        }
    });
    return closeBracketArray;
}
function TestingRules() {
    var openBrackets = GetOpenBrackets();
    var closeBrackets = GetCloseBrackets();
    var closeBracketIndex;
    var openBracketIndex;
    for (openBracketIndex in openBrackets) {
        if (openBrackets[openBracketIndex] !== "") {

            var foundCloseBracketIndex = -1;
            for (closeBracketIndex in closeBrackets) {
                if (openBracketIndex <= closeBracketIndex) {
                    if (closeBrackets[closeBracketIndex] !== "") {
                        foundCloseBracketIndex = closeBracketIndex;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (foundCloseBracketIndex > -1) {
            var openBracketCheck;
                for (openBracketCheck in openBrackets) {

                    if (openBracketIndex < openBracketCheck && closeBracketIndex >= openBracketCheck) {
                        if (openBrackets[openBracketCheck] !== "") {
                            alert('error');
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }

    // for testing:
    //  console.log(OpenBracketArray.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just keep a counter, or count paren stack depth? If you inc for open parens, dec for closing, and the counter goes above 1, you have an error. (If I've understood your requirements correctly.)

Comment: Used this as the answer as it was the easiest to implement with my minimal JS knowledge. The other post is probably very valid but I didn't quite understand it as easily as this.  Plus this is a very easy obvious solution.

Comment: @Piercy It's essentially the same as the stack, at least in terms of counting parens. The stack would also allow expression evaluation--it's a more general-purpose solution. The difference is an inc/dec/numeric compare vs. push/pop/stack size compare.

Answer (score 1):

I **believe** that you can simply try implementing

a conceptual `stack(top=0)` and

`push(top=top+1)` whenever you see `(` and

> [(optional) if top>X , where X is the depth allowed, error out invalid expression length]

`pop(top=top-1)` whenever you see `)`.

When the expression completes and you still have anything left on `stack(top>0)` you can infer that expression is not balanced.

Comment: The stack is the right way to go here, but he wants no nested brackets with a depth > X, so the answer should also mention that the stack must never have more than X item(s) on it at a time

Comment: This is simpler and works for 1 or more. So if the solution is simpler enough why not go for it.

Comment: True, I was just saying if the OP has a reason to not exceed 1 layer of depth, then the answer should reflect that

Comment: Will be checking it out now and let you know :). Not overly familiar with JS so, the stack, push and pop stuff is new to me. Research ahead and then ill get into it. Thanks

Comment: Used the other reply as the answer as it was the easiest to implement with my minimal JS knowledge. This post is probably very valid but I didn't quite understand it as easily as the other (even with research).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to find a pair of brackets, why not just search for two open brackets in a row?  When you find the first open bracket, one of two things are possible: Either the content that follows is enclosed with a close bracket (so the user didn't nest them), or you find another open bracket.  If you find another open bracket, the user is trying to nest statements.  This saves you from having to go back and searching the same space again.